# Does higher vega imply higher IV and vice versa

Tags: option-pricing, implied-volatility, greeks, vega

If an option A has higher vega than option B, does that also mean that A has a higher IV than B?
I understand that by definition, a higher vega means that A's price is more sensitive to its IV than B.

But can we conclude that A has higher IV than B also?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put, no. Vega depends on a variety of factors (including the level/price of the underlying asset). However, vomma/volga/**vega convexity (whatever you want to call dVega/dIV) is always positive**. So as IV increases, the vega of an option increases - I think this might have been what you were getting at.

It's important to understand that IV is an input to a pricing model while the greeks are the sensitivity of options prices to various input factors (as @vonjd correctly states).

Comment: "So as IV increases, the vega of an option increases"...yes this was my question. Thank you

Comment: Why is vega convexity (=vol gamma = volga) always positive?

Comment: dVega/dIV is NOT always positive!  In particular, for an at-the-money option it is slightly negative.

Answer (score 4):

IV is one of the inputs for your option pricing model, vega measures the actual impact (e.g. in Dollars, Euros...) of any change in IV.

Intuitively IV *is* the price of the option while vega is the *sensitivity* to IV.

Bottom line: There is a clear distinction!